# generating dynamic Twiml response and save on Nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

So i am following a tutorial to create the XML doc for twilio like as a `response`, 
(https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html)

***but rather than sending it as a response, I want to generate the file on my server to access later.***

something like -  **localhost/files/USERNAME/FILENAME.xml**

this is my current code that sends the file as a response.

---

```
  var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

  resp.say({voice:'woman'}, 'Thanks for calling!');

  //Render the TwiML document using "toString"
  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type':'text/xml'
  });

  res.end(resp.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the response from Twillio to your localhost by using the `fs` library built into node.  Specifically:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Once you have your .xml file saving to localhost, you can use an express route with `res.sendFile()` that sends back the `.xml` file.
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As tomato points out, you can use the build in `fs` library from Node. You could do that like below:

```
var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

resp.say({voice:'woman'}, 'Thanks for calling!');

//Render the TwiML document using "toString"
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type':'text/xml'
});

// Save the XML to disk, then return the response to Twilio.
fs.writeFile('twilio-response.xml', resp.toString(), function(err) {
  res.end(resp.toString());
});
```

You may want to generate a unique file name for each response so that they don't get written over.

Just in case this helps, Twilio does save the TwiML responses that you send back and you can retrieve these in your [call log](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls).